# ¿Cómo realizar un gráfico de densidad kernel exponencial?

Tags: r

Hola quiero realizar un gráfico de funciones kernel en R, pero que incluya la función exponencial. He realizado lo siguiente  pero no se como agregarle la función exponencial:

```
(kernels <- eval(formals(density.default)$kernel))
plot(density(0, from = -1.2, to = 1.2, width = 2, kernel = "gaussian"),
     type = "l", ylim = c(0, 1), xlab = "",
     main = "R's density() kernels with width = 1", lwd=2)
for(i in 2:length(kernels))
  lines(density(0, width = 2, kernel =  kernels[i]), col = i, lwd=2)
legend(0.6, 1.0, legend = kernels, col = seq(kernels), lty = 1)
```

Como observaran solo incluye las siguientes funciones  "gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular" , "triangular" ,  "biweight", "cosine" ,    "optcosine"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
kernels <- eval(formals(density.default)$kernel)
# Creamos un plot totalmente en blanco
plot(1, type = "l", xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 0.6), xlab = "",
     main = "R's density() kernels with width = 1 plus exponential", lwd=2)

# Dibujamos las funciones de kernel de density
for(i in 1:length(kernels)) {
  lines(density(0, from = -5, to = 5, width = 4, kernel =  kernels[i]), col = i, lwd=2)
}

# Agregamos la fun. exponencial
kernels <- c(kernels, "exponential")

x <- seq(from=-5, to=5, by=.1)
y <- .5 *exp(-abs(x))
lines(x, y, col = length(kernels))

legend("topright", legend = kernels, col = seq(kernels), lty = 1, border = "white")
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunos comentarios

- Modifiqué un poco la lógica del `for`, para que grafique todas las lineas partiendo de un plot en blanco
- Ajuste el valor de `width` para que la gráfica sea similar a la del ejemplo en python
- La función exponencial la dibujamos generando algunos `x` e `y`, la formula `.5 *exp(-abs(x))` la adapte del ejemplo que diste de python.
- El color de la línea es el que le da automáticamente la función `lines`, y cae justo en un gris muy clarito, así que dibujé la línea un poco más gruesa que las otras para poder apreciarla.

Answer (score 0):

En R, la distribución exponencial se obtiene usando `dexp` así:

```
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out=1000)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, px=dexp(x, rate=0.65))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=px)) + geom_line()
```

El resultado:

[image: Distribución exponencial con R y ggplot]

Fuente: [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705964/236345)

Comment: Pues gracias por la respuesta sin embargo, lo que quiero hacer es un gráfico multiple que incluya la función kernel exponencial.

Comment: Pues gracias por la respuesta sin embargo, lo que quiero hacer es un gráfico multiple que incluya la función kernel exponencial como el de la figura del siguiente enlace pero en r ya que no manejo python: https://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter6/fig_kernels.html